# C# Selenium frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt condition not being waited for

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've been struggling to make Selenium wait until an iframe is loaded to switch to it, despite reading several things that seem to have worked for other people.

I have tried this with and without the `IgnoreExceptionTypes` call. As far as I can tell some variation on this is what I want, but when I do it this way, I always get a `NoSuchWindowException`, and I get it immediately. However, I know my window exists because if I instead do a `Thread.Sleep(5000)` before I try to switch to the frame, it works.

Very little else happens before this: I go click on a link that will create the iframe

Am I doing something wrong with the wait, or with the Expected Conditions? Or is there something else I haven't considered

```cs
var waitForFrameToExist = new WebDriverWait(Driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15));
waitForFrameToExist.Until(
    SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(
        By.CssSelector("#AccountSettingsContent > iframe")
    )
);

var wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15));
wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(StaleElementReferenceException),
                          typeof(WebDriverException),
                          typeof(NoSuchWindowException));
wait.Until(
    SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.FrameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(
        By.CssSelector("#AccountSettingsContent > iframe")
    )
);
```

The html for the iframe is:

```
<div id="mainBody">
    <div class="tabContent" style="display: none;" id="HomeContent">
        <iframe src="/page/source/"></iframe>
    </div>
    
    <div class="tabContent" id="AccountSettingsContent">
        <iframe src="/otherPage/Source"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that the frame is dynamically added through javascript, which is why I included the check for the element existing (this does not fail).

I am using ChromeDriver 84.0.4147.3001 and DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers 3.11.0, if that is helpful at all (should be latest nuget packages)

Comment: What is the value of `iframeCssSelector`? Can you post the relevant HTML for the page?

Comment: Updated with code and a little extra info.